# MongoDB Unique objectId in document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, keystonejs

i want to prevent having the same document data twice EX
This is fine

```
 { _id:objectId("5e693defc65ac2bd8d0c4406"), name: Jhon stage: objectId("5e6929bd725f97bc9a98be3b", day: objectId("5e69298c725f97bc9a98be38") } 

 { _id:objectId("5e693defc65ac2bd8d0c4407"), name: Jhon stage: objectId("5e6929bd725f97bc9a98be3b", day: objectId("5e69298c725f97bc9a98bswe") }
```

But i want to prevent this

```
 { _id:objectId("5e693defc65ac2bd8d0c4406"), name: Jhon stage: objectId("5e6929bd725f97bc9a98be3b", day: objectId("5e69298c725f97bc9a98be38") } 

 { _id:objectId("5e693defc65ac2bd8d0c4407"), name: Jhon stage: objectId("5e6929bd725f97bc9a98be3b", day: objectId("5e69298c725f97bc9a98be38") }
```

how can i achive this on mongodb level i mean when making the DB models ?

here is my DB Schema

```
Stage.add({
      name: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
      },
});

Day.add({
  name: {
    type: Types.Date,
    unique: true
  },
});

  Session.add({
  name: { type: String, default: '', required: true },
  day: {
    type: Types.Relationship,
    ref: 'Day',
    index: true,
  },

  stage: {
    type: Types.Relationship,
    ref: 'Stage',
    index: true,
  },


});
```

Comment: You could create a compound unique index, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/index.html

Comment: can you show me an example using my models?. if it's not too much trouble :)

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much i will mark it as duplicate <3